# supanase signup give error as <!DOCTYPE html> although I'm using Flutter

Tags: flutter, supabase-flutter

I'm developing a Flutter app using also Supabase , when signup a new user I get an AuthException as shown bellow, no user registered at auth.users table; is this error about "Enable JavaScript and cookies to continue" and how to solve ..or is it other error type ?

```
  Future<void> _signUp() async {
   try {

    await supabaseClient.auth.signUp(
      password: _passwordController.text,
      email: _emailController.text,
      //phone: phoneNumberProvider!.phoneNumber,
      //emailRedirectTo: '',
      data: {
        //'email': _emailController.text,
        'mobile': phoneNumberProvider!.phoneNumber,
        'is_super_admin': false,
      },
      //captchaToken: '',
      //channel: supa.OtpChannel.whatsapp,
    );
    if(mounted){
      context.go('/b');
    }

} on AuthException catch (error) {
  print(error.message);
  
} catch (exc) {
 Flushbar()..show(context);
}
```

Error:

```
I/flutter (25510): <!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en-US"><head><title>Just a moment... 
</title><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"><meta 
http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge"><meta name="robots" 
content="noindex,nofollow"><meta name="viewport" content="width=device- 
width,initial-scale=1"><link href="/cdn-cgi/styles/challenges.css" 
rel="stylesheet"></head><body class="no-js"><div class="main-wrapper" role="main"> 
<div class="main-content"><noscript><div id="challenge-error-title"><div 
class="h2"><span class="icon-wrapper"><div class="heading-icon warning-icon"> 
</div> 
</span><span id="challenge-error-text">Enable JavaScript and cookies to 
continue</span></div></div></noscript></div></div><script>(function() 
{window._cf_chl_opt={cvId: '2',cZone: "zbpexovyytqwkhvjsqnq.supabase.co",cType: 
'managed',cNounce: '23633',cRay: '81b7b4524e0a2df5',cHash: 
'61736d56a9c0e4e',cUPMDTk: "\/auth\/v1\/signup? 
__cf_chl_tk=6l99InZ2x3cYcst2iNhYXTbagyr4gIeB51eL3tCuf_Q-1698208018-0- 
gaNycGzNDFA",cFPWv: 'g',cTTimeMs: '1000'
```